# Simple example in omnetpp-4.6

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate this scenario in omnetpp-4.6: a set of mobile nodes, when two nodes meet each other they exchange messages.

There is an existant example in the simulator that does this scenario which can be a starting point for me?

Answer (score 0):

The [INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org/) offers a lot of examples for this.